# Magento 2 static files URL fail

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, base-url, static-content

after reading the official guide here [Magento Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html) I have setup my magento this way:

- I have created one website in english and one in spanish
- I have configured Apache this way

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>         ServerName www.mywebsite.devcom
>         ServerAlias www.mywebsite.devcom
>         DocumentRoot /var/www/magento/
>         ErrorLog /var/log/mywebsite/es/error.log
>         CustomLog /var/log/mywebsite/es/access.log combined
>
> <Directory /var/www/magento>
>   Options FollowSymLinks
>   AllowOverride All
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all
> </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- I have configured HTACCESS this way

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite\.devcom
> RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:base]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite\.devcom
> RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite\.deves
> RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:spain]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite\.deves
> RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
> ```

- I have configured Magento backend to have different URL for base url and static files url
  [image]

The result is that Magento is loading the HTML page but all static content have 404 error since doesn't load from domain cdn.mywebsite.deves.

I have checked my configuration and I don't understand if there is an error in the Magento guide or something in my setup or a bug in the Magento code.

Anybody is experiencing the same issue?

Comment: `mod rewrite` is ON on Server?

Comment: [More info about Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite)

Comment: Hi, yes mod_rewrite is enabled on the server and in my host file on my mac I have added the cdn DEV domain and I can ping the server correctly from that domain, I really don't know why magento is accepting just the www and  ignore any subdomain. Is my htaccess rule correct?